# Clearing a form on page load, trouble with multiple forms in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have 2 forms in JSP
Form1 contains dropdown which when selected fetches value from DB and through session attribute I display the values in form 2

```
<form id="form1">
    <button id="submit" name="submit" onclick="submitButton()">Submit</button>                     
</form>

<form id="form2">
Many fields fetched from DB
</form>
```

submitButton makes an AJAX call to servlet where DAO performs the DB fetch.

I am trying to clear form 2 on every page reload. While the form clears the first time, on every reload, form is auto populated with last values.

I also wrote a resetForm method

```
 function resetForm() {
                // clearing inputs
                var form = document.getElementById("form2");
                var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    switch (inputs[i].type) {
                        // case 'hidden':
                        case 'text':
                            inputs[i].value = '';
                            break;
                        case 'radio':
                        case 'checkbox':
                            inputs[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }

                // clearing selects
                var selects = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
                for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++)
                    selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;

                // clearing textarea
                var text = form.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
                    text[i].innerHTML = '';
            }
```

But when I invoke resetForm in body onload , my DB values are populated in form2 and instantly get cleared.

Pls help

Comment: Have you tried the reset function of the form element? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

Comment: _“on every reload, form is auto populated with last values”_ - presumably due to the fact that you stored the choice from the first form into the session …? Why are you doing that in the first place then? If you are sending that value to the server in your AJAX request, then you _have_ access to it at that point, so that you can create the appropriate response to populate the second form with it. So why are you pushing stuff into the session?

Comment: @04FS Do you mean to say its a better approach to use the AJAX response to fill the form as opposed to setting a whole bean in session and using its values to populate form.

Comment: I mainly saying it sounds as if the putting something in the session part is probably the main cause of your problem - because when the page gets reloaded, that stuff _will be_ in the session already, but apparently you don’t want the effect that has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well clearly I stumbled upon the solution.

I added a Clear form button in form 1 and realized that on its addition, the form got cleared on every page reload :) so i just made the button hidden and that solved my problem ! Dirty hack maybe but works :D

```
<button id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear Form"
                            style="background-color: #37617A; color: white; padding: 8px 20px; margin: 8px 0; border: none; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;"
                        hidden="hidden" onclick="resetForm()">Clear Form</button>
```